# Can't add new value in C# List<char[]>

Tags: c#

I have a simple recursive program to find all the distinct permutation of a given string. I am using a recursive function `go()` to calculate the permutations and using a `List<char[]>` to store the permuations. After a calculation, the function checks whether the permutation already exists in the `List<char[]>` or not. If it doesn't, it gets added to the List<>.

Now here is the problem, the permutations are getting calculated perfectly but when i try to add them to the list, it't not adding the current value. Here is the code that does the adding.

```
List<char[]> l;
public void go(char[] list, int k, int m)
{
if (k == m)
{
     Console.WriteLine(list); //print to check
     l.Add(list); //add it to the list
}
// more code
}
```

Now for **input=ABC**, i get the following output..

```
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CBA
CAB
```

which is correct because i am printing it directly. but when i print the list, i get.

```
ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
```

Now i know i am making just a simple mistake somewhere but i can't figure out what. I have tried this in a bunch of different ways but nothing seems to work and i can't find any answer on the internet. [Here is the complete code](https://ideone.com/x4664R).

Comment: @EugenePodskal can you elaborate a little, i am a newbie in c# and i don't understand how does that relate to my question?

Comment: Though you haven't shown the code that [reproduces the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is obvious that your `char[] list` is always the same reference, thus all those `l.Add(list);` actually add the same value that will be changed by the following call. Each item in the `l` is **the same** reference, that references the same array, array that can obviously can contain only one value.

Comment: so why does it prints the correct value in the statement `Console.WriteLine(list)` and not adding the correct value in the list in the very next statement `l.add(list);` and sorry for the badly formatted question.. although i have added a link to the complete code in the question and [here it is again](https://ideone.com/x4664R)

Comment: Because it is correct at the exact moment - you have just calculated it and then printed it. Nothing could have changed it in between. But on the next iteration (call) it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is already given in the comments on your question, the problem you're experiencing is that on this row:

```
l.Add(list); //add it to the list
```

you are adding a **reference** to the "list" array in the "l" list, you are not making a **copy** of the array. So basicly you are left with a list full of references to the same object.

Try changing this

```
List<char[]> l;
```

to this

```
List<string> l;
```

and switching this code

```
l.Add(list); //add it to the list
```

for this

```
l.Add(new string(list)); //add it to the list
```

And I Think you will receive the expected result.
The difference is that we have converted the array (that is a reference type) into a string (that behaves like a value type)

Comment: thnks man... it worked...